# blend colors in polygon

Tags: opencv, graphics, geometry, computational-geometry, blending

I have a polygon which consist of segments of different colors (red and green on sample image).

And for each pixel in polygon (grey area) I need to calculate coefficients to obtain the color of pixel:
pix_color= red * Ca + green * Cb

Boundary condition is that on border color coefficients must be =1 (for example Ca=1 Cb=0 for red boundary).

So I want to achive "smooth" transition from red to green in inner area of polygon.

How can I do it?

[image]

**Update 2:**
I tried algorithm for 3 color borders and non-convex polygon.
[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8841028/blending/polygon_full.png]

here is my opencv code

```
 //a=red border,b=green,c= blue, da,db,dc min dist to borders.
    Vec3b pix_ab; 
    pix_ab[2]= r_a*db/(da+db)+r_b*da/(da+db);
    pix_ab[1]= g_a*db/(da+db)+g_b*da/(da+db);
    pix_ab[0]= b_a*db/(da+db)+b_b*da/(da+db);
    Vec3b pix_ac; 
    pix_ac[2]= r_a*dc/(da+dc)+r_c*da/(da+dc);
    pix_ac[1]= g_a*dc/(da+dc)+g_c*da/(da+dc);
    pix_ac[0]= b_a*dc/(da+dc)+b_c*da/(da+dc);
    Vec3b pix_bc;
    pix_bc[2]= r_b*dc/(db+dc)+r_c*db/(db+dc);
    pix_bc[1]= g_b*dc/(db+dc)+g_c*db/(db+dc);
    pix_bc[0]= b_b*dc/(db+dc)+b_c*db/(db+dc);

    img(y,x)[0]= (pix_ab[0]+pix_ac[0]+pix_bc[0])/3;
    img(y,x)[1]= (pix_ab[1]+pix_ac[1]+pix_bc[1])/3;
    img(y,x)[2]= (pix_ab[2]+pix_ac[2]+pix_bc[2])/3;
```

but problem is that for example by condition blue border affects not on all polygon area, but on some subarea and if I use my formula I get noticeable difference on border of areas, so I think I need somehow to force blue color to be =0 on border of subarea.

[image]

Comment: [Bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) is not suitable for you? You just get the color from the four edges, as paul suggested. The number of colors in the edges is irrelevant, you just add the RGB values.

Comment: @George Aprilis I don't understand which points I need to choose in case of polygon.

Comment: dividing the polygon in triangles using the edges would be the best option, but I think the method that paul mentioned should work. If you interpolate each of the R,G,B values in the same way, then the color of the edge can be anything.

Comment: can you draw an example?

Comment: Of the polygon triangulation or the RGB interpolation?

Comment: I don't understand your idea maybe you mean something like this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16168/quirk-in-vertexcolors-interpolation-when-displaying-polygon ?

Comment: yes. It's described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation), but the point is that triangulation is a whole new algorithm that you have to develop or find. And if you polygon is non-convex then it's extra work. Did you try paul's answer and it didn't give satisfying result?

Comment: yes, I tried, see update. I hope there is simple solution without triangulation.

Comment: I didn't quite understand, the second figure (first output from Opencv), why is it not acceptable? The code you paste creates the first figure or the second?

Comment: It creates 1st and 2nd image, but in 2nd blue border have influence only in subpolygon. Also I think my formula is not right, because it makes image darker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each internal pixel 4 values, indicating the distance up, down, left, right to the nearest edges. Use the lowest green, and lowest red values to calcuate Ca and Cb.

i.e. for the pixel crudely marked on my diagram, I would suggest it is 40 from red, and 20 from green, or twice as green as red, or Ca = 0.333 and Cb = 0.666

[image]

Comment: Ok,I understand. But how can I do this for 3 or more colors (see update).